# List of static methods from an instance in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, static, extjs4

I have an instance of a class (e.g Ext.data.Model) `myRecord` and need to call one of its static methods (e.g `getFields()`). How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use the [self](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-statics) property to get the class:

```
myRecord.self.getFields();
```

Comment: Interesting that `myRecord.statics().getFields()` does not work (probably because it is simply scope-independent).

Comment: Yes, it's the scope-independence. `statics()` would only work if you instanciate Ext.data.Model directly. However, usually you'll define your own models which extend from Ext.data.Model, so you'd only get the static properties you defined there (if any).

Answer (score 2):

You need the class of that instance and then simply call the static method.
E.g:

```
var myClass = Ext.ClassManager.getClass( myRecord );
myClass.getFields();
```